# HTML: Allow-Same-Origin on iframe, but I am not using iframes

Tags: javascript

i am stuck here for a while now.

I have this simple button in vanilla

```
                <td><button class="button_accept" onclick="acceptInvite(event, 0)" type="submit">accept</button></td>
```

It fires this script:

```
async function LoadPaymentController(){
  var stripe = Stripe('testKey');
// Call your backend to create the Checkout Session
fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
  method: 'POST',
})
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(session) {
  return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
})
.then(function(result) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, you should display the localized error message to your
  // customer using `error.message`.
  if (result.error) {
    alert(result.error.message);
  }
});
}
```

But whenever I click this, firefox tells me that:

```
Stripe.js requires 'allow-same-origin' if sandboxed.
```

I spoke to a dev from the stripe team and I googled my ass off and it always says that I have to add the sandbox="allow-same-origin" attribute to my iframe.

But I am not using an iframe.

Adding this attribute to everything else also didnt work at all.

What am I missing?

I tried:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="allow-same-origin">

  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

To no avail

Comment: The error most likely concerns about CSP of the page, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox

Comment: Yes, don't get hung up on the wording. It's not only for iframes, it means the HTML in general.

Comment: @PeterKrebs hi Peter, ok... but can you give me an example on how to alter my code or html to get this rest call to work? :)

Comment: Congrats! This is a well-made question. I praise!

Comment: @innom Good, that seems correct. If you don't have console errors regarding this then you did your part. How about stripe.js? It seems there is [a related react-stripe-elements issue](https://github.com/stripe-archive/react-stripe-elements/issues/391). So it seems stripe is generating an iframe which is initialized incorrectly. So probably not even your fault.

Comment: @PeterKrebs as it turns out, it wasnt my fault. running the application from server and not from vanilla solved all issues ... three days wasted (anyway, customer pays by the hour ) :D

Comment: Heh well sometimes that's like a free lunch. At least that's solved for you. 